# How get a Set<Object> of a bean with JSTL

Tags: spring, jsp, set, jstl, javabeans

i have a complex bean that contain a Set field. I wont to access at this element from my jsp page.
My "Sito" bean object is this:

```
public class Sito {
    @Id
    @Column(name="idSITO")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idSito;
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Bene.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "installazione", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idSito") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idBene") })
    private Set<Bene> beni;

    public Set<Bene> getBeni() {
         return beni;
    }
    public void setBeni(Set<Bene> beni) {
        this.beni = beni;

    }

    public String getListBeniString(){
        String listBeniString="";
        for(Bene b:beni){
            listBeniString += b.toString();
        }
        return listBeniString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.err.println("idSito " + getIdSito()+" "+getListBeniString());
        return "Sito [idSito=" + idSito + ", nome=" + nome + ", fi=" + fi + ", lambda=" + lambda + ", h=" + h + ", ente=" + ente + "]";
    }
        /* Other get and set... */
}
```

"Bene" bean is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bene")
public class Bene {
    @Id
    @Column(name="idBENE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idBene;

    private String tipo;
    private String nome;
    //get and set
}
```

on my jsp page the controller pass me a List< Sito > and i wont to iterate on "beni" field. My jsp code is this:

```
<c:forEach items="${listSiti}" var="sito">
    <c:forEach items="${sito.beni}" var="bene">
        <label>${bene.idBene}</label>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

The page is it not rendered and is blank.
What is wrong?

Comment: You can't iterate on "beni" field because it's not initialized.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the JSP code you posted. Maybe listSiti is empty. Maybe all the siti have an ampty set of beni. Maybe you got an exception on the server. Maybe you forgot to declare the JSTL lib in the JSP. Add some debug code, look at your console, at the logs. Use your debugger.

Comment: "beni" field is it initialized by Hibernate. i have omissed the annotation and now i have added it. If i print the content of "beni" with auxliary function the output is correct. "listSiti" doesn't empty and "beni" is loaded correctly by Hibernate. JSTL lib is declared in my jsp. I have solved by cleaning cache and restarting server.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I have noticed a very strange behavior. I have writed "toString()" and "getListBeniString()" for debugging and i have noticed that if i comment the line of code  "System.err.println("idSito " + getIdSito()+" "+getListBeniString());" in Sito Bean the page is blank, if i maintain it, the page result is correct.

With the line of code the server logging is this:

```
   Hibernate: select sito0_.idSITO as idSITO1_3_, sito0_.ente as ente2_3_, sito0_.fi as fi3_3_, sito0_.h as h4_3_, sito0_.lambda as lambda5_3_, sito0_.nome as nome6_3_ from sito sito0_
   idSito 2 Bene [idBene=4, tipo=Bananone, nome=lksdbsdfb]Bene [idBene=2, tipo=Radio multicanale, nome=jjjjj123]Bene [idBene=3, tipo=Transmitter, nome=9ui234]
   Hibernate: select beni0_.idSito as idSito1_3_0_, beni0_.idBene as idBene2_2_0_, bene1_.idBENE as idBENE1_0_1_, bene1_.nome as nome2_0_1_, bene1_.tipo as tipo3_0_1_ from installazione beni0_ inner join bene bene1_ on beni0_.idBene=bene1_.idBENE where beni0_.idSito=?
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=2, nome=Scoglio Eugenio, fi=50.0, lambda=20.0, h=541, ente=CP - Roma]
   Hibernate: select beni0_.idSito as idSito1_3_0_, beni0_.idBene as idBene2_2_0_, bene1_.idBENE as idBENE1_0_1_, bene1_.nome as nome2_0_1_, bene1_.tipo as tipo3_0_1_ from installazione beni0_ inner join bene bene1_ on beni0_.idBene=bene1_.idBENE where beni0_.idSito=?
   idSito 3 
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=3, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.0, lambda=0.1, h=84, ente=CP - Cagliari]
   Hibernate: select beni0_.idSito as idSito1_3_0_, beni0_.idBene as idBene2_2_0_, bene1_.idBENE as idBENE1_0_1_, bene1_.nome as nome2_0_1_, bene1_.tipo as tipo3_0_1_ from installazione beni0_ inner join bene bene1_ on beni0_.idBene=bene1_.idBENE where beni0_.idSito=?
   idSito 5 
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=5, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.23, lambda=0.1, h=83, ente=CP - Cagliari]
   Hibernate: select beni0_.idSito as idSito1_3_0_, beni0_.idBene as idBene2_2_0_, bene1_.idBENE as idBENE1_0_1_, bene1_.nome as nome2_0_1_, bene1_.tipo as tipo3_0_1_ from installazione beni0_ inner join bene bene1_ on beni0_.idBene=bene1_.idBENE where beni0_.idSito=?
   idSito 6 
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=6, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.23, lambda=10.0, h=84, ente=CP - Cagliari]
   idSito 2 Bene [idBene=4, tipo=Bananone, nome=lksd<bsdfb]Bene [idBene=2, tipo=Radio multicanale, nome=jjjjj123]Bene [idBene=3, tipo=Transmitter, nome=9ui234]
   idSito 3 
   idSito 5 
   idSito 6
```

and no error on browser.

If i comment the line "System.err.println("idSito " + getIdSito()+" "+getListBeniString());" the server log is this:

```
   Hibernate: select sito0_.idSITO as idSITO1_3_, sito0_.ente as ente2_3_, sito0_.fi as fi3_3_, sito0_.h as h4_3_, sito0_.lambda as lambda5_3_, sito0_.nome as nome6_3_ from sito sito0_
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=2, nome=Scoglio Eugenio, fi=50.0, lambda=20.0, h=541, ente=CP - Roma]
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=3, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.0, lambda=0.1, h=84, ente=CP - Cagliari]
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=5, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.23, lambda=0.1, h=83, ente=CP - Cagliari]
   INFO : com.spring.dao.SitoDAOImpl - Sito List::Sito [idSito=6, nome=Punta Gabbiano, fi=20.23, lambda=10.0, h=84, ente=CP - Cagliari]
```

and no error on browser, but the page is blank.

A piece of my controller is this:

```
   @Controller
   public class ReamController {
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReamController.class);

   /*-----------------------SERVICE---------------------------*/
   private SitoService sitoService;
   @Autowired(required=true)
   @Qualifier(value="sitoService")
   public void setSitoService(SitoService ss){
     this.sitoService=ss;
   }

   ...
   ...

    /*----------------------Installazioni-----------------------------*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ricercaInstallazione", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRicercaInstallazione(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listSiti", this.sitoService.listSiti());
        return "ricercaInstallazione";
         }
    }
```

is it very strange....